# NodeJS + MySql nested queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to get users from database and then loop throug each user and get their images. However when I try to assign images array to user.images property nothing happens. I still get only users with empty images array.

Currently my code is the following:

```
user.getAll().then(result =>{
    const userCollection = result[0];

    for(let i=0; i < userCollection.length; i++){
        userCollection[i].images = [{}];  
        image.getImagesByUserId(userCollection[i].Id).then(res =>{
            userCollection[i].images = res[0];
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).json(err);
          })              
    }        
   res.json(userCollection);
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json(err);
  });
```

Why I can't assign images array to it's property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to run your res.json(userCollection) from inside the callback.

This will of course mean you need to rename your res variable in the callback

This is assuming you are somehow using res.json(userCollection) to export the information. Which I am inferring based on the fact I don’t see res defined anywhere

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is how the full call looks:

router.get('/' , (req, res) => {    


  ...code from the question

   
});

Can you please advise where to put res.json(userCollection); to make it work correctly?

Comment: It should go directly bellow userCollection[i].images = res[0]

Answer (score 0):

May be a silly question, but are you assigning it? I only see

userCollection[i].images = [{}];

above and never see:

userCollection[i].images = res;

assignment once you grab the images.

Comment: good catch - but I was assigning it, just missed it here. Just edited my code

Comment: Just to be clear - when i console.log res[0] - I see my images, but when I try to assign it - it stays empty property

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getImagesByUserId()` is asynchronous so by the time you get to the assignment, you've already sent the response.

The order of events you have currently is:

1. Assign an empty image list to all the users
2. Queue up a load of database requests
3. Send the response (`res.json()`)
4. Reassign the images for all the users once the database results come back.

The easy fix is to look at [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and aggregate the results when they all come back.

However, this isn't the most efficient way to deal with SQL databases, I would suggest you restructure your query so that you get all the images for all the users in 1 trip to the database and then format the response based on those results.

Say you have an image table and a user table, something like:

```
SELECT image_name, user_id
FROM image
```

then replace your loop in your js with:

```
getImagesForUsers().then(result => {
  //create your response from the rows
  res.json(response);
});
```

Comment: I tried several options with Promise.all() but I am pretty new to JS and node so I can't find a good example.

Regarding single query - do you mean it's better to get from database common array users+images and and try to sert them out in .then statement?

Comment: Yes it's better to get all the data you need from the database in one go than making lots of small queries.

Comment: Another thing that would help you is using the async await keywords rather than using then.

Comment: See "Creating an array of promises" on http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptpromises.shtml for a similar example to yours on promise.all()